# NetBeans Modules and the "Force Install Into Shared Directories" option for plugins

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I'm writing a NetBeans Plugin for an application that is built upon the NetBeans Platform.  The plugin installs just fine and runs, but my customer has a use case where it would be useful to have the plugin installed for all users, rather than having each user install the plugin manually.

To that end, the NetBeans Platform has a plugin option for installing a plugin to a shared location (in NetBeans: Tools-> Plugins; click on the Settings tab on the far right; look for Plugin Install Location at the bottom).

What I'm confused about is how the Shared Location is determined?  I've heard it has something to do with the NBM Cluster path ([What is a Cluster?](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/main/wiki/DevFaqWhatIsACluster/)), but I can't find any information regarding how to use the Cluster to set the install path.

What does happen is that when I install to the User Directory, I get an obvious install to my home directory (`\home\$USERNAME\.appname`).  When I install to the Shared Directory, it installs to `\root\.appname`.

Obviously, installing to `\root` is not the desired behavior.

Does anyone have an idea how I can configure the Platform application or my NBM Plugin to install to a better location?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this helps but under https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/main/wiki/FaqPluginManagerCustomization/ there's a paragraph "Install all plugins into NetBeans installation directory" which sounds promising